# How is OFFSET supposed to work on filtered EXCEL data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

Consider:

```
    +---------------+
    | Column A      |
+---+---------------+
| 1 | Milan         |
+---+---------------+
| 2 | Paris         |
+---+---------------+
| 3 | London        |
+---+---------------+
| 4 | Milan         |
+---+---------------+
| 5 | Firenza       |
+---+---------------+
| 6 | Napoli        |
+---+---------------+
| 7 | Amsterdam     |
+---+---------------+
| 8 | Copenhagen    |
+---+---------------+
| 9 | Amsterdam     |
+---+---------------+
```

Suppose I filter Column A to look for cities in Italy. The following results are returned.

```
    +---------------+
    | Column A      |
+---+---------------+
| 1 | Milan         |
+---+---------------+
| 4 | Milan         |
+---+---------------+
| 5 | Firenza       |
+---+---------------+
| 6 | Napoli        |
+---+---------------+
```

Now, consider the following expression:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($AR5,Copy!$I$1:$K$3,2,0),OFFSET($A$1,2,0))`

Does `OFFSET` refer to the WHOLE of the source data -- in which case my default value in case of error would be `London` -- or only the result set -- in which case my default value in case of error would be `Firenze`?

I'm seeing inconsistent results in my worksheet, and what to narrow down my debugging options by undrrstanging what's supposed to happen in this circumtance.

Comment: Answers [here also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25515606/2662901).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First regarding debugging formulas in general:

The best way to do this is to use the `Evaluate formula` functionality (in the `Formula`tab). This gives you a very good way to see what happens in each step/parameter. Also, if you highlight a part in your formula (e.g. the comple OFFSET formula), press <kbd>F9</kbd>. This will evaluate the highlighted statement in the formula bar.

The OFFSET will return `London`, as OFFSET will also consider hidden cells.

If you want to return the second visible cell, you need a small trick involving an extra column: Place the formula `=SUBTOTAL(3,A1)+C1` in C2 (assuming that your table starts in row 1 and column C is available. Then copy the formula down. It will now show you a counter for all visible cells, i.e. the numbers will change according to your autofilter.

Now the formula `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(2,C:C,0))`will return you the second visible element.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe `OFFSET()` excludes hidden/filtered data. From the example below, you can see that even when part of the data is hidden/filtered, the formula in `C1` points to the same cell.

[image]

To get the 3rd visible item from your list, you may use this array formula<sup>1</sup>:

```
=INDEX(xmen,
       SMALL(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(xmen,ROW(xmen)-ROW(A2),0,1)),ROW(xmen)),3)-1,1)
```

Where:

**`xmen`** → refers to your data range excluding any headings (`A1:A9` in your example, `A2:A9` in the sample below)
**`A2`** → points to the first item in your range (non-heading)

For example:

[image]

--
***<sup>1</sup>*** Must be committed/entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> after you integrate it with your VLOOKUP formula

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple with this:

```
=VLOOKUP(SUBTOTAL(5,A:A),A:B,2,FALSE)
```

It finds the smallest number that is visible (subtotal `5` is minimum)
and `vlookup` the value (which also takes the first value found with that index number).